# Deploy Minio distributed on 3 nodes with 1 drive

Tags: storage, object-storage, minio

I need to deploy a [MinIO](https://min.io/) infrastructure on three nodes, where each nodes has a single local directory where they can save files in.

I read the [MinIO Erasure Code Quickstart Guide](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-erasure-code-quickstart-guide.html), but I don't need MinIO to manage data replication on different local drives because all three nodes are on separated virtual machines on separated hardware and the local storage is already protected by ZFS.

For this reason I only MinIO replicates data between nodes creating three replicas of each files, but when I try to start it with a single data directory it fails:

```
minio@storage3:/usr/local/bin$ export MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=foo
minio@storage3:/usr/local/bin$ export MINIO_SECRET_KEY=bar
minio@storage3:/usr/local/bin$ ./minio server http://storage{1...3}/minio1
ERROR Invalid command line arguments: Invalid total number of endpoints for erasure mode.
      > Please provide correct combination of local/remote paths.
      HELP:
        For more information, please refer to https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-erasure-code-quickstart-guide
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: AFAIK if you start MinIO in distributed mode, it only works with erasure coding - i.e. using data replication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minio needs at least 4 instances, try add one more and it should start working.

Comment: This will make erasure-coding to kick-in, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

A Minio cluster can setup as 2, 3, 4 or more nodes (recommend not more than 16 nodes).  As long as the total hard disks in the cluster is more than 4.

For example, if you have 2 nodes in a cluster, you should install minimum 2 disks to each node.

If you have 3 nodes in a cluster, you may install 4 disks or more to each node and it will works.

Number of disks is the key factor here, not number of nodes.

Comment: if I have 3 nodes and 4 disks per each https://github.com/minio/operator/blob/master/helm/minio-operator/values.yaml#L84 does it mean I can lose one node and service is still up for writing?